# Convert a json value to a enum value

Tags: json, angular, typescript, serialization, enums

I like to convert a json string value to enum so it can show/render a custom string on the html page.
error message: Type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Status[]'

I have a json record like this:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'Some name', status: 'STATUS01' },
```

status.enum.ts

```
export enum Status {
  'STATUS01' = 'Operational',
  'STATUS02' = 'Some other status'
}
```

That enum is used in a model

```
import { Status } from './status.enum';

export class ServiceState {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  status: Status;
}
```

In the service there is a function to retrieve al statuses (dummy data):

```
getStatuses(): Observable<ServiceState[]> {
    const response = [
      { id: 1, name: 'One', status: 'STATUS01' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Two', status: 'STATUS01' },
      { id: 3, name: 'OneTwo', status: 'STATUS02' },}
    ];
    return of(response);
  }
```

the return is throwing the error

Comment: Please add the code which threw the error.

Answer (score 3):

You should actually use the enum value:

```
export enum Status {
  STATUS01 = 'Operational',
  STATUS02 = 'Some other status'
}

const response = [
  { id: 1, name: 'One', status: Status.STATUS01 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Two', status: Status.STATUS01 },
  { id: 3, name: 'OneTwo', status: Status.STATUS02 },
  // ...
];
```

---

If you want to map the values from the enum:

```
getStatuses(): Observable<ServiceState[]> {
  const response = [
    { id: 1, name: 'One', status: 'STATUS01' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Two', status: 'STATUS01' },
    { id: 3, name: 'OneTwo', status: 'STATUS02' },
  ];

  return of(response).pipe(
    map((states) => states.map((state) => ({
      ...state,
      status: Status[state.status]
    } as ServiceState)
  );
}
```

Comment: the webapi will return a STATUS01 (string) not Status.STATUS01. This is some dummy data.

Comment: @Babulaas Then your typing is incorrect, or you have to map the value in your response

Comment: I had to map the values. I had a long day. thank you for the fix.

Comment: @Babulaas But it's not even 4pm in Holland :D, you should try to work less, otherwise your productivity will go down too much!

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand your question, but you might have to map the response from the API to match your class type.

Service

```js
public getStatuses(): Observable<ServiceState[]> {
  return this.http.get('url').pipe(
    map(data => data.forEach(item => {
      item.status = Status[item.status];
    }))
  );
}
```

<sup>If you're using the class only to assert the type, then a simple interface would suffice.</sup>